# Calendar Webpart to Subsite

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-calendar

Is there a way to make a webpart of a top level calendar and then have it show on a page of a subsite.  The thought process is that you have a public calendar for the entire organization, however one of the segments of the organization could go to their subsite and see only their data, allowing the President of the organization the ability to add things to all calendars.

I have used Sharepoint Designer to create webparts of lists, however cannot seem to find a solution for a calendar.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar overlays.

You create your calendars separately, but in each section you overlay the other calendars on top of them.

So if you have:
Home
Dept. A
Dept. B

On Home
Home Calendars with Overlays for Calendars in Dept. A and Dept. B
Dept. A Calendar has Home and Dept. B calenders overlayed.

This doesn't scale very large - you can only add up to 10 overlays, and there is a bit of work upfront to make them work.

Comment: That wont' work as we are using one top level calendar for all subsites.  The list view shows up fine, it's the calendar view that doesn't want to play nicely. It shows the events but doesn't let me add an event, comes up with list does not exist error.

Comment: Your not going to get something OOTB than to help.  You need to look at some type of workflow to push/pull that data from the master calendar.